# Reference for the ViewBase class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to C# and .NET. I am trying to change the 'view' for a ListView. [This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does this to change the view:

```
lv.View = lv.FindResource("tileView") as ViewBase;
```

I get an error that ViewBase cannot be found. The tutorial files have the following using's:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

When I try to include System.Windows.Controls or several other System.Windows.* in my own Windows Forms project, I get an error ("are you missing an assembly directive?"). I tried to add the same references as the tutorial project, but the same references were not in my available list. The references from the tutorial project that I could not add include PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, and WindowsBase.

I'm not sure what's going on here. Is this because the tutorial project is a different type of project than mine?

Comment: What is your targeted framework? Are you using wpf or win forms

Comment: @ArunChandranC I am using win forms. Targeting .NET framework 4.5.